# no consigo traer el id de una tabla a otra cuando registro

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código para registrar

```php
<?php
// Insertar datos en la tabla 'usertable' para el administrador de la empresa

$insert_admin_data = "INSERT INTO usertable (name, email, password, code, status, role )
                      VALUES('$company_name', '$admin_email', '$encpass', '$code', '$status', '$role')";
$admin_data_check = mysqli_query($con, $insert_admin_data);

if ($admin_data_check) {
    $admin_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); // Obtener el ID del administrador recién insertado 

    
// Insertar datos en la tabla 'company' para la empresa
$insert_company = "INSERT INTO company (id, name, admin_email)
                   VALUES('$admin_id', '$company_name', '$admin_email')";
$company_data_check = mysqli_query($con, $insert_company);
?>
```

La idea es que con este código , se guarde la misma id de company en usertable ,
Company registra la empresa y usertable genera los usuarios para el inicio de sesión en la plataforma , pero al registrarlo lo hace exitosamente pero company_id sigue vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así esta la estructura de usertable

y así la table company

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que company_id no envias el dato para guardarlo, lo tienes autoincremental ?

Comment: Podrías compartir la estructura de tus tablas en formato SQL? Con la información que compartes es complicado ayudarte. Te recomiendo realizar el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y luego puedes ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .